# Dynamic return type based on an array argument

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that will return an object whose keys are going to be the same as the values of the input array:

```
type PathParam = 'userId' | 'groupId' | 'commentId';

function usePathParams(params: PathParam[]) {
  return params.reduce(
    (acc, param) => ({ ...acc, [param]: 'whatever' }),
    {} as Record<typeof params[number], string>,
  );
}

// OK
const { userId } = usePathParams(['userId', 'commentId']);
// Should be an error but is not
const { userId, groupId } = usePathParams(['userId', 'commentId']);
// Passing a tuple doesn't seem to work either
const { userId, groupId } = usePathParams(['userId', 'commentId'] as const);
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get an error on your second case, we need to use a generic to know which specific keys were passed.

```
function usePathParams<Params extends PathParam>(params: Params[]) {
  return params.reduce(
    (acc, param) => ({ ...acc, [param]: 'whatever' }),
    {} as Record<Params, string>,
  );
}
```

We now get the desired error *Property `groupId` does not exist on type `Record<"userId" | "commentId", string>`*

Your third example still has an error because `as const` makes the tuple `readonly`.  If you wanted to support this, you would change the function arguments to `(params: readonly Params[])`.  That actually allows both readonly and mutable arrays.  It says that we only require read functionality.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I tried using a generic but I must have done something wrong.